# Rotate in jQuery else

Tags: jquery, transform

I try to make navbar-toggler using jQuery but "else" don't work with me

```
$("#__chn").click(function () {
if($(".jax2").css("display","block")){
    var r__o_t = 50;
    var n_r_ot = -50;
    var n = 0;
    $(".jax2").css({"display":"none"})
    //$(".jax1").css({"transform":"translate(20%)"})
    $(".jax1").css({"transform":'rotate('+ r__o_t +'deg)'})
    $(".jax3").css({"transform":'rotate('+ n_r_ot +'deg)'})

 } else {
    $(".jax2").css({"display":'block'})
    $(".jax1").css({"transform":'rotate(none)'})
    $(".jax3").css({"transform":'rotate(none)'})
 }
});
```

When I click "if" work but "else" doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [:visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) in your conditional statement instead.

```js
$("#__chn").click(function () {
if($(".jax2").is(":visible")){
    var r__o_t = 50;
    var n_r_ot = -50;
    var n = 0;
    $(".jax2").css({"display":"none"})
    //$(".jax1").css({"transform":"translate(20%)"})
    $(".jax1").css({"transform":'rotate('+ r__o_t +'deg)'})
    $(".jax3").css({"transform":'rotate('+ n_r_ot +'deg)'})

 } else {
    $(".jax2").css({"display":'block'})
    $(".jax1").css({"transform":'rotate(none)'})
    $(".jax3").css({"transform":'rotate(none)'})
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="__chn">Click Me</button>

<div class="jax2">Show/Hide</div>
```